# Is there an auto test framework that tracks passing asserts?

Tags: unit-testing, assert, googletest, xunit

I'm looking for a unit test framework that tracks every assert in the code, pass or fail. I looked into Google Test, which is based on xUnit, and it only tracks failures. I need this because I work in a company that makes medical devices and we must keep evidence of validation that can be audited by the FDA. We want a test report that tells you what the test did, not just that it passed. Also, the framework would have to be usable with POSIX C++.

Ideally what I would like to have is something like this (using Google Test syntax):

```
EXPECT_EQ(1, x, "checking x value");
```

and the test would generate a report that has the following for every assert: a description, the expected value, the actual value, the comparison type, and a pass/fail status.

It looks like I'll have to create my own test framework to accomplish this. I stepped into the code of Google Test to verify it really does nothing for a passing assert. I wanted to see if there were other ideas, such as a framework that could accomplish this or be modified to accomplish this before creating my own.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply generate a json/xml/html report as part of your build process and then check that file into some kind of source control?

Comment: I don't understand how that would solve the issue. The issue isn't generating or storing the report, it's having the data to generate the report from. Knowing what tests ran and their status isn't sufficient. Tests need to track everything the did, i.e. all asserts executed, including ones that pass.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for clarifying.